Dependency duplicate crashes in Xcode with Unity
Having issues with Unity-iPhone integration using CocoaPods, while my native app uses Swift Package Manager, both having duplicate dependencies, thus causing crashes.
I am trying to integrate 'Unity as a library' into our app following the same approach described in this video.
Based on this approach you create a workspace that includes your native app (in Swift), then integrate Unity-iPhone .xcodeproj and usually things tend to work fine. However problems start to arise when we try to integrate multiple dependencies.
Currently, our native app uses Swift Package Manager to integrate some third party libraries like Firebase, thus bringing its dependencies like Promises, nanopb, GoogleUtilities, etc. The Unity-iPhone .xcodeproj for the AR experience uses also some third party libraries that are integrated through CocoaPods (from what I understood from the agency that provide the Unity-iPhone, pods are generated when they are building the app in Unity), the pod looks something like this:
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
    pod 'ARCore/GARSesion'
    pod 'ARCore/Geospatial'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

This will also bring third party libraries like Firebase, FirebaseCore, GoogleUtilities, nanopb, PromisesObjC, etc. And when I try to run the app it has a 50% chance to crash, so not every time it  crashes, and while looking at the logs I see things like these:
objc[8347]: Class GULURLSessionDataResponse is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/298197D2-7D84-4120-84EC-9A5E1C1D8A77/MyApp.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x117a8c258) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/298197D2-7D84-4120-84EC-9A5E1C1D8A77/MyApp.app/MyApp.debug.dylib (0x10846edf8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[8347]: Class FBLPromise is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/298197D2-7D84-4120-84EC-9A5E1C1D8A77/MyApp.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x117a89ce8) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/298197D2-7D84-4120-84EC-9A5E1C1D8A77/MyApp.app/MyApp.debug.dylib (0x10846ee98). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[8347]: Class GULLoggerWrapper is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/298197D2-7D84-4120-84EC-9A5E1C1D8A77/MyApp.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x117a8c190) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/298197D2-7D84-4120-84EC-9A5E1C1D8A77/MyApp.app/MyApp.debug.dylib (0x10846ef60). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

And when it crashes, I see this:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3024bc510'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18995d08c 0x186c5f2e4 0x189a637c8 0x1898fa888 0x1898fa1b0 0x114fcd9bc 0x114fcca04 0x114f03978 0x114f0319c 0x102e0ca30 0x102e0e71c 0x102e16800 0x102e17360 0x102e245f0 0x102e23c00 0x210ca7c7c 0x210ca4488)

I think it is because I manually put UnityFramework.framework into the native iOS project, which will bring up all its dependencies.
I've tried to replicate the same behaviour on another small app that I started from the ground up, by including Swift Package Manager into the native project, pods into Unity-iPhone generated project (yes, I had to install Unity for this), and the result is almost the same, I get the 'is implemented in both' in the logs but it never crashed this time, maybe because I was not calling a Firebase function other than FirebaseApp.configure().
I've had no prior experience with Unity integration, neither with multiple Xcode projects into a Xcode workspace, neither with dependencies coming from frameworks manually integrated, I would really appreciate your help for this! Thanks in advance!

Use CocoaPods for all the dependencies.
It is very challenging to use both package managers in the same app
